# Not able to locate org.openqa.selenium class using ant to run a webdriver script

Tags: ant, classpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using Apache ANT to run my webdriver script.
My project structure is as follows:

```
ant_webdriver_project
 - src
   - test.ant.webdriver
     - TestLogin.java
 - JRE System Libraries
 - Referenced Libraries
    - all jars including selenium-java-2.25.0.jar, selenium-java-2.25.0-srcs.jar
 - build
 - lib
    - all jars including selenium-java-2.25.0.jar, selenium-java-2.25.0-srcs.jar
 - resources
    - myproperties.properties
 - build.xml
```

and my build.xml file is:

```
<project basedir=".">

<property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

 <target name="clean">
     <delete dir="build"/>
 </target>

 <target name="compile">
     <mkdir dir="build"/>
     <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build"/>
</target>

<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="build/jar/testlogin.jar" basedir="build">
         <manifest>
           <attribute name="Main-Class" value="test.ant.webdriver.TestLogin"/>
         </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java fork="true">
    <classpath>
        <path refid="classpath"/>
        <path location="build/jar/testlogin.jar"/>
    </classpath>
    </java>

</target>
```

Now when i go for ant compile I get this:

> [javac] Compiling 1 source file to
>   /home/abhijeet/Automation_Dev/automation_workspace/ant_webdriver_project/build
>       [javac] /home/abhijeet/Automation_Dev/automation_workspace/ant_webdriver_project/src/test/ant/webdriver/TestLogin.java:11:
>   package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
>       [javac] import org.openqa.selenium.By;
>       [javac]                           ^
>       [javac] /home/abhijeet/Automation_Dev/automation_workspace/ant_webdriver_project/src/test/ant/webdriver/TestLogin.java:12:
>   package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
>       [javac] import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
>       [javac]                           ^
>       [javac] /home/abhijeet/Automation_Dev/automation_workspace/ant_webdriver_project/src/test/ant/webdriver/TestLogin.java:13:
>   package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
>       [javac] import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
>   .
>   .
>   .
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   /home/abhijeet/Automation_Dev/automation_workspace/ant_webdriver/build.xml:18:
>   Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

The errors are related to all the webdriver objects that I have used in my class. I think there must definitely be a problem with the way i have constructed my build.xml but I looked into many sources but couldn't find any solution. I'm completely new to ANT. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long time since I've used ant, but in your `compile` target, you don't have a `classpathref`:

```
<target name="compile">
     <mkdir dir="build"/>
     <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build" classpathref="classpath" />
</target>
```

Comment: hi, So i have modified the build.xml as you suggested. Now, i'm not getting the errors that I mentioned in the post.
I'm now getting:
run:
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/ant/webdriver/TestLogin
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.ant.webdriver.TestLogin
    ............
     [java]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
     [java] Could not find the main class: test.ant.webdriver.TestLogin. Program will exit.
     [java] Java Result: 1

Is there any good practice to manage classpaths?

Comment: Your jar target should depend on compile, compile should depend on clean.